# Calling a model's method from outside Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model with some static methods. I'd like to call the methods from outside the application (cronjob).

The model I have:

```
class Job(models.Job):
    #Irrelevant information

    @staticmethod
    def methodIwantToCall():
        #statements
```

I have the following python file that I'm using for the cron job:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from myapp.models import Job

Job.methodIwantToCall()
```

At first, I was having an error about `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE not being set` and I fixed that, however, now I have the following error: `No module named myapp.utils`

I feel like I'm doing something that I'm not supposed to do. So how do I call that static method the way I want it to be called?

EDIT: It looks like the paths are getting messed up when I'm importing from outside Django. For example, I have an import in my models file, when I call the cron file it fails importing with the message `ImportError: No module named myapp.utils` even though it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is to create [custom manage.py command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it to see if I have enough knowledge to do it :P.

Comment: I ended up using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cron job code resides in the same directory as your settings file, use the following setup code at the beginning:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

Comment: The cron job code resides in the same directory. I'm still having the same error about not being able to import Utils.

python cron_fetch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cron_fetch.py", line 13, in <module>
    from myapp.models import Job
  File "C:\apps\myapp\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from myapp.utils import beautifyDict
ImportError: No module named myapp.utils

Comment: OK, maybe you could resolve this by using relative imports such as `from utils import beautifyDict` in your `models` file. However, creating a custom manage.py command as mentioned by @DrTyrsa might be the better solution altogether.

Comment: thank you. It looks like a relative path thing that I need to solve. I will look into the custom manage.py thing even though I think it's a little bit over my head.